# Cannot connect to SQL Server using pyodbc - login failed

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

When using T-SQL, I am able to connect to my SQL Server instance with no issue but when I run the same in Python using pyodbc/freetds, I get logon denied.

`odbc.ini`

```
[MSSQL]
Description         = Test to SQLServer
Driver              = FreeTDS
Servername          = MSSQL
```

`odbcinst.ini`:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS
Driver for Linux & MSSQL
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount=1
```

`freetds`

```
[MSSQL]
    host = IP
    port = port
    tds version 7.3
```

T-SQL statement:

```
tsql -S MSSQL -U "username" -P "password"
```

Python statement:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=MSSQL;UID=username;PWD=password")
```

Python error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/username/Documents/Python Script/MSS Sql Connection Script.py", line 3, in 
>   conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=MSSQL;UID=username;PWD=password")
>   pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'username'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Any help?

Comment: Seems like the username or password is incorrect. Can you see the login attempt in the SQL Server logs?

Comment: It would be a *lot* better if you used Microsoft's [ODBC client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of FreeTDS. FreeTDS is missing critical functionality like parameters. Think Bobby Tables

Comment: Check the [step-by-step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15) tutorial that shows how to connect using `pyodbc` and the ODBC driver